# I need to display an an immediate tooltip on some buttons using and event filter(PyQT5). How can I install a filter for button1 and 2

Tags: python, pyqt5

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import password_checker
import pyperclip
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QEvent,QObject
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(890, 651)

        #NEW
        MainWindow.setFixedSize(890, 651)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.bg = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.bg.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 890, 651))
        self.bg.setObjectName("bg")
        
        
        path = 'C:/Users/cheik/OneDrive/Desktop/WORK/pass/main/bg.jpeg'
        self.bg.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(path))
        self.bg.setScaledContents(True)
        
    
        self.button1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 300, 121, 51))
        self.button1.setObjectName("button1")
        
        #NEW
        self.button2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(750, 300, 100, 51))
        self.button2.setObjectName("button2")
          

        self.button3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 300, 121, 51))
        self.button3.setObjectName("button3")

        self.label1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 210, 231, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setFamily('arial')
        self.label1.setFont(font)
        
        self.label1.setObjectName("label1")
        self.header = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.header.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 0, 701, 91))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        font.setFamily('arial')
        self.header.setFont(font)
        self.header.setObjectName("header")
        self.label2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 210, 231, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setFamily('arial')
        self.label2.setFont(font)
        self.label2.setObjectName("label2")
        self.text1 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.text1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(550, 300, 200, 51))
        self.text1.setObjectName("text1")
        
        self.output = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.output.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 390, 701, 91))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        font.setFamily('arial')
        self.output.setFont(font)
        self.output.setObjectName("output")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 890, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

        #NEW
        self.button1.clicked.connect(self.passGen)
        self.button2.clicked.connect(self.passCheck)
        self.button3.clicked.connect(self.passGen2)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Pass Generator/Checker"))
        self.button1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Basic"))
        self.label1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Generate New Password"))
        self.header.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Welcome to the password generator/checker!"))
        self.label2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Check Password Strength"))
        #NEW
        self.output.setText(_translate("MainWindow", ""))
        self.button2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ENTER"))
        self.button3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Advanced"))

    #NEW
    def passGen(self):
        newPass = password_checker.passGen()
        self.output.setText(newPass)
        self.output.adjustSize()
        self.output.move(320, 400)
        msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox()
        msg.setStyleSheet("color:black;background:white}")
        msg.setText(newPass + "\nHas been copied to clipboard")
        msg.setWindowTitle("Copy")
        msg.move(520,600)
        msg.exec()
        pyperclip.copy(newPass)

    def passGen2(self):
        newPass = password_checker.passGen2()
        self.output.setText(newPass)
        self.output.adjustSize()
        self.output.move(320, 400)
        msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox()
        msg.setStyleSheet("color:black;background:white}")
        msg.setText(newPass + "\nHas been copied to clipboard")
        msg.setWindowTitle("Copy")
        msg.move(520,600)
        msg.exec()
        pyperclip.copy(newPass)
    
    #NEW
    def passCheck(self):
        text = self.text1.text()
        val = ""
        if len(text) == 0:
            self.output.setText("Please Enter Something!")
            self.output.adjustSize()
            self.output.move(270, 400)
        else:
            val = password_checker.passCheck(text)
            self.output.setText(val)
            self.output.adjustSize()
            self.output.move(270, 400)     

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    #NEW
    app.setStyleSheet('QPushButton {background-color: black; color: white;} QLabel {color: white;}')
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: ignore the fact that the top half and bottom half is normal text and the rest is code. Its my first time using stack overflow <3.

Comment: Please improve your post by adding more details to the question (not to the title), and also explain what you tried and how. Then also read [ask], review the [checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648) and read [how to properly format code](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361). Finally, remember that you are ***not*** expected to edit pyuic generated files (as pointed out in the warning that you ignored and removed) but instead follow the official guidelines about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html)

Comment: Ok thanks for the advice, ill fix up my formatting. As for the pyuic generated file its a little too late haha I added quite a lot to it. Is there anything that can be done? Thanks in advance <3

Comment: It's not too late, and, most importantly, your subclass would never work as an event filter, because only QObject subclasses can do that. Be patient, create a new file (which will be your actual "main" script), start implementing as described in the above link about Designer, merge your changes and rebuild the ui file with pyuic. Don't try to "fix" your current classes just because you don't want to update your code, because sooner or later you'll find yourself in a nightmare of workarounds and be forced to switch to the correct approach anyway. Then it *will* be late, and quite painful too.

Comment: Wow thanks for your clear and concise explanation. I will take your advice. <3